# Eslint object-property-newline does not work

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have `"object-property-newline": ["error", { "allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine": true }],` and `"max-len": "off",` in my `.eslintrc` but objects like

`const something = {a: 5, ffsdfasdasdsddddd: 'asdasdasdddddddddddssssssddddddddd'};`

still gets split into multiple lines if they are longer than 80 characters, how do I stop this?

Answer (score -1):

Check the value of:
`"printWidth": 140,` and adjust here the max. number of characters per line

Comment: Tried that, not satisfied with the result. Then Eslint is not happy about so many lines. Can I disable printWidth at all? I meant it looks disabled until I specify it explicitly...